# How to generate new sheet from find result?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to generate new sheet for all values contains "_S" :

Example:
[image: Excel example]

When user click on "Generate page", two new sheet are created (one sheet with title "Folder22_S" and other one with title "Folder3_S"

In second time, i would like that new sheet generated from a model (not generate a empty sheet)

My question is: How to do this ? I doesn't know how to find all values contains "_S" and get cell value ( Folder22_S and Folder3_S) ?

My pseudo VBA code:

```
Sub generate()
    'Array contains all values *_S'
    Dim AllValuesContains_S As Variant
    AllValuesContains_S = Array("Folder22_S", "Folder3_S", ...)
    For Each item As String In AllValuesContains_S
      Sheets.Add.Name = item
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a "Code for me" site. Display your efforts and the community will help you work through your issues.

Comment: You are right, i added my code. I doesn't know which function used to find all elements contains _S (regex *_S ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume the range you want to search is A2:C7. Adjust that portion of the code to be whatever range you need.

```
Sub New_Wksht()
Dim SearchRange as Range, c as Range
Dim sht as Worksheet
With ThiwWorkbook
   Set SearchRange = .Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Range("A2:C7") 'Change sheet name and range to be what you need
   For Each c in SearchRange
      If Right(c.Value,2) = "_S" Then
         Set sht = .Sheets.Add
         sht.Name = c.Value
      End If
   Next C
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx. I added End With and change sheet name. Now i am finding a solution to create new sheet from a template.